# Generalized type of array in parameter of function

Tags: c, casting

I have the function:

```
void print_sum(int list[], int length) {
    float sum = 0.0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sum += (float) list[i];
    }
    printf("Sum: %0.2f\n", sum);
}
```

I want, in the same function, can receive a array of `int` or a array of `float`, for example. How I can make it?

Comment: You can probably do that using all kinds of assumptions but don't. Define two functions, one for `int`s and one for `float`s (or `double`s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, this could be done with a template. But in C, you can accomplish something like this with macros.
One way is to replace the function with a macro:

```
#define PRINT_SUM(list,type,format,length) do{ \
      type sum = 0;                            \
      int i;                                   \
      for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {           \
          sum += (type) list[i];               \
      }                                        \
      printf("Sum: " format "\n", sum);        \
    }while(0)
```

To use this, write something like `PRINT_SUM(a,float,"%0.2f",3);`.

The other way is to define a macro that defines a function which receive a list of a given type:

```
#define DEFINE_PRINT_SUM(name,type,format) void name(type list[], int length) { \
     type sum = 0.0;                                                            \
     int i;                                                                     \
     for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {                                             \
       sum += (type) list[i];                                                   \
     }                                                                          \
     printf("Sum: "format"\n", sum);                                            \
   }
```

Then you can define a float version of `print_sum` with `DEFINE_PRINT_SUM(print_sum_float,float,"%0.2f")`.